# What is the best way to check a .TXT extension file for CSV format data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, csv, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I need to Export & Import TXT file fill-up with CSV format data. I need want to do it in MVC4. What is the best approach to do this ?

Txt file can contain a large number of CSV format data,

Answer (score 2):

Just run it through a CSV parser (I've used [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) in the past - worked fine) and check that it makes semantic sense, and has the same number of columns on each row. That would be very unlikely if it wasn't CSV data. Note: columns != commas - you need to watch out for quoted data `"like, this"`, and line-breaks - both of which a parser will help you with. You cannot just `Split` by `','` or use line-endings to detect rows - CSV is more complex than that.

Comment: nice response and touch!

Comment: @Marc Gravell: thanks for quick reply. I just go through your CSV Parser. `new StreamReader("data.csv")`. is specifically looking for csv extension file ?

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh it was Andrei who mentioned CSV Parser and `StreamReader` - but: it won't care hat the extension is; you're just saying "open this file"

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to check the file extension, then using `lastIndexOf` or `Split` will pretty much do an excellent trick for you.

Using `endsWith`

```
String myFile = "some.file.txt";
        System.out.println(myFile.endsWith(".txt"));
```

Using `split`

```
String myFile = "some.file.txt";
String[] myFileArray = myFile.split("\\.(?=[^\\.]+$)");
if (myFileArray[myFileArray.length - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("txt")) {
    System.out.println("Ends with .txt");
}
```

Comment: There are standard framework methods for doing this - primarily `Path.GetExtension`

Comment: @MarcGravell, As usually you're right! Didn't knew them, just used custom made. But it always better using the Framework. ( btw Mark commented me ;) )